# unit zabbix-agent.service is masked

Tags: systemd, zabbix, zabbix-agent

When i try to start/restart/stop/status the zabbix-agent service. I get the following error. I precise that I have made an install and then purged - removed it to install another version (upgrade). and since that I get this error:

```
Failed to start zabbix-agent.service: unit zabbix-agent.service is masked.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to unmask zabbix-agent service?

```
systemctl unmask zabbix-agent.service
```

Comment: It was helpfull for me systemctl unmask zabbix-agent systemctl enable zabbix-agent